# Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I find a basic spring security example, but I can't run it usually on tomcat.
I know this error message might be caused by the configuration xml file, but I can't find it.
Thanks for the help:)

`1. Error Message`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotated
Methods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefiniti
onReader.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader
.java:318)
```

`2. File Structure`

[image]

`3. web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`4. mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>mymessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`5.spring-security.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
             />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a part of your `stacktrace`:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoC
lassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/config/AbstractInterceptorDrivenBeanD
efinitionDecorator
```

which says that `Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework` jars are not present in the `classpath`. So you need to add `spring-aop` (spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar) jars to your `classpath`.

Comment: After I add the `spring-aop`, I still have some error message.

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: Yes! I find I lose `org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add spring.jar to your library. spring-security jars would be referencing it. Hence failing initialization.

Comment: Is org.springframework.core.jar not the spring.jar??

Comment: open and see if it has this class... org/springframework/aop/config/AbstractInterceptorDrivenBeanDefinitionDecorator. I think you also need spring-aop.jar

Comment: You are right!!! But I still have some error message. I have edit my post. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

I found same exception in my project but after adding spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar i resolved the problem. please be careful about the version of jar which you are going to add in your project... :)